# Floating Plastic bag in Air with Wind

Tags: physics, soft-body, force-fields

I tried to recreate a plastic bag after watching a tutorial but failed to achieve the desired look. The plastic bag is supposed to be floating and moving with the wind but instead, while playing the animation, the bag loses its form and kind of collapses even though self-collision is turned on. The physics of the object (plastic bag) is set to soft body and I added turbulent and wind to the scene.

best,
Jassim
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111663/29586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using cloth instead of soft body. I think that gives you better behaviour and control.
2. Make sure you object is made out of quads and they have roughly the same sizes. Especially for bending animations it's crucial that quads are as undistorted as possible. Then maybe add a subd modifier before your simulation. Keep in mind that the subdivisions an object has the smaller the wrinkles of cloth animations will be so ideally you use a subd before the simulation to give it enough geometry to work with and add another one after the simulation to smoothen the result.

Comment: Thank you, The cloth physics seems to give a better result in terms of structural integrity but the force fields don't affect the object. Why does that happen?

Comment: Make sure that in the Field Weights panel of the cloth simulation all influences are set to 1. If you want more of a floating behaviour, you could however lower the gravity instead of counter the falling with a wind field. As for the force fields you may need to increase the strength. I quickly setup a sim with a subd-ed cube, a wind pointing upwards with a strength of 200 and a turbulence field with a strength of 1000 and size of 0.2. You could also watch a tutorial by Ian Hubert, who explains exactly what to do. He does indeed use soft bodies but maybe it helps you to figure out the setup.

Comment: Thank YOUUUUUUU!!!! It worked like a charm, Yeah the tutorial that I was mentioning working on was indeed that of Ian Huberts.